# Total Area of infinitely many triangles (Using Sums)

Tags: calculus

So the question is as follows: [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQedw.jpg)

I understand that in order to answer the question I must take the sum of all the areas of the triangles using a geometric series, however when I try to do that I fail (this is an online homework question.)

When I did a similar problem where the height was 1/2 and the points on the bottom were (from left to right) 1/8, 1/4, 1/2, 1 I got an answer of 1/4 which was correct by making a series:
[Answer to alternate problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoSA0.jpg)

For some reason I cannot solve the first problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the area of several triangles is the same as the area of one triangle with an equivalent base.

$$\sum_i\frac12\times b_i\times h=\frac12\times h\times\sum_i b_i$$

[image]

The left hand edge of each triangle is at $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$. Taking the limit of this gives you a total base of 1 of all the triangles. The height is $\frac{5}{6}$ so the area is $\frac12\times1\times\frac56=\frac{5}{12}$

Comment: I understand now. However I'd just like to ask are you taking the limit of (3/4)^n as n goes to 0? Why?

Comment: The limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$. As there are infinitely many triangles.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

The bases are $1- \frac 3 4, \frac 3 4-\frac 9{16},\cdots, \left(\frac {3}4\right)^n-\left(\frac {3}4\right)^{n+1},\cdots$ and the heights are always $\frac 5 6$.

Can you go on?